# Locking down public site access in a billing panic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

One of the scary things about being a small fish in the AWS ocean is what seems to be unlimited liability in the unlikely event of a flood of transactions on a publicly exposed service. AWS is designed for the big guys, for whom availability is the be-all and end-all. There's a great deal of effort in keeping services up, but apparently none when it comes to saving us from astronomical bills. Amazon seems to have been repeatedly asked for a spending cap, but AFAIK, the best they've come up with is billing alerts. I've read some horror stories, like the guy who set up a small website for family and friends and got a bill for $10,000. The best Amazon has done is provide billing alerts, and what if you are AFK? Quite large sums could disappear before you can shut down.

So, my cunning plan - to write a Lambda fired from a billing threshold event which raises the drawbridge and shuts down any public facing facilities.

So, I started with CloudFront and that's quite do-able, though disabling a distribution take some time to propagate.

Now we come to my first technical quandary. I thought I could just check all the buckets for public permissions and revoke them. But, since I last looked in detail at S3, there's this static website setting. So, how do I, programmatically, turn this off? Obviously I don't want to delete the bucket. To my surprise turning this on does not create a public permission in the ACL. There's a service in the API to update properties on one of these static websites, but not to revoke it.

It seems to be somewhat the same with the API gateway. You can delete an API, but not suspend it. And if you delete it, then re-building will probably give you a different hostname, which creates some hastle.

I'm trying to write a fairly generic Lambda and make it public domain.

Answer (score 1):

#### To Answer Your Question...

For API Gateway, you can lock it down by [creating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/usageplan-create/) or [updating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/usageplan-update/) the usage plan to have a throttle rate limit of 0. That will mean that any requests to that API will be responded to with a `HTTP 429 — To many requests`. In the past, AWS did charge for throttled requests, but since 2016, [that is no longer the case](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=740246#740246), so a throttle rate limit of 0 will prevent your API from being used or incurring charges. (You should also set the throttle burst to 0 at the same time if you want to lock it down immediately.)

For S3, you can lock down a bucket by [blocking all public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) either [for the entire account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTAccountPUTPublicAccessBlock.html) or [for a specific bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTPublicAccessBlock.html).

#### The Simpler Way

That being said, I think there's a simpler solution to all of this. You can use API Gateway as a [proxy endpoint for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) or for [pretty much any AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html). You can then set a UsagePlan for that endpoint with a monthly, weekly, or daily quota, which limits the total number of API requests allowed to that API gateway endpoint.

The great thing about this is that you don't have to just react to your budget notifications. You can proactively set a limit on how much your website can be used. However, you do need to keep in mind that this approach doesn't entirely protect you from a huge bill. (If you allow public access to upload files to your S3 bucket, it is possible that someone uploads a 5TB file, which would incur about $100/mo in storage costs. However, this scenario is unlikely and it is easy to prevent by just not allowing uploads.) You also need to understand the pricing models of the services you use in order to set appropriate limits on your proxy APIs.

Comment: Thank's. I'll chase up the limiting on the API gateway and, as you say, if you can throttle that, you can protect other resources.

Comment: I thought that closing the public access in the acls on S3 would do the job, but to my surprise I discovered, by experiment, that the static website setting on S3 buckets doesn't seem to depend on the acl. Setting a bucket as a static website appears to have no effect on the ACL, and vica-versa. I was expecting that the static website route would either require public read access, or have it's own entry in the ACL, which could be cut. It doesn't seem to. There seems no way of switching if off using the ACL.

Comment: Oh I see. It's the ACL on the Object, not on the bucket that allows the page to be served. It would seem the way to go would be to use the PublicAccessBlock for the bucket, not the ACL.

Comment: So far, what I haven't been able to do using the API gateway as a proxy to S3 is to return image data, which is mostly what I was trying to do in the first place.